# How to join rows with single columns to a maximum of 4 columns in one row?

Tags: text-processing, awk, perl

I have a file looks like below:

```
1 
4 5 6 7 19
20
22
24 26 27 
29
30
31
32 
34 
40 
50 
56 
58
100
234 235 270 500
1234 1235 1236 1237
2300
2303
2304
2307
2309
```

As it is clear there are some rows with more than 1 column and some others with only one single column. I'd like to join together single-column rows  such that there are at most 4 columns on each combined row. So the output should look like this:

```
1  
4 5 6 7 19
20 22
24 26 27 
29 30 31 32
34 40 50 56 
58 100
234 235 270 500
1234 1235 1236 1237
2300 2303 2304 2307
2309
```

Any suggestions on how do this, considering that the real data is big?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little bit idiomatic but working with gnu awk:

```
awk '{printf "%s",(NF==1?$0 FS:(c==0?"":RS) $0 RS)} \
{(NF==1?++c:c=0)} \
c==4{printf "\n";c=0} \
END{printf "\n"}' file

#Output
1 
4 5 6 7 19
20 22 
24 26 27
29 30 31 32 
34 40 50 56 
58 100 
234 235 270 500
1234 1235 1236 1237
2300 2303 2304 2307 
2309
```

Explanation:
**awk variables:**
NF=Number of Fields
FS=Field Separator = space by default
RS=Record Separator= new line by default.
c=counter

**Line1:** `{printf "%s",(NF==1?$0 FS:(c==0?"":RS) $0 RS)}`: nested ternary if operations

```
#Single ternary if operation:
condition?true action:false action
#Nested if operations:  
condition1?true action 1:(condition2:true action2:false action2) #nested ternary if operations   
-------------------------[            ^ false action1 ^        ]
```

This can be explained in pseudocode like:

```
if NF==1 then print $0 and print FS   
else (if c==0 then print "" else print RS) and print $0 and print RS again
```

**Line 2:** `{(NF==1?++c:c=0)}` : Another ternary if operation that can be expressed as:

```
If NF==1 (line has one field) 
then increase counter c by one 
else reset counter c.
```

**Line 3 :** `c==4{printf "\n";c=0}` Classic awk syntax : `condition{action}`

```
If counter c==4 then print a new line and reset counter c
```

**Line 4:** `END{printf "\n"}' file` : This justs prints a new line at the end of the script.

Comment: Ugh, this might be a bit more understandable with at least a bit of explanation added, or at least a more friendly formatting? Just saying. :)

Comment: @ilkkachu OK - Added some basic explanation and a bit better formatting. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Are extra interfield spaces and trailing spaces a big deal? Your solution have them both :) - I have run it just now. Should we care about it or it is unimportant in this case? I was care about it in the my solution.

Comment: @MiniMax Default field separator of awk (FS) is actually whitespace and this include one or more spaces. A basic awk like `awk '{print $2}' <<<"one two"` will work either with one space between fields or with more spaces .

Answer (score 2):

You may use `sed` to get what you want:

```
sed -e '
   /./!b
   /[^[:space:]]/!b
   /[^[:space:]][[:blank:]]\{1,\}[^[:space:]]/b

   :loop
      $q;N
      /\n.*\S[[:blank:]]\+\S/b
      s/\n/ /;tdummy
      :dummy
      s/[[:space:]]\{1,\}/&/3;t
   bloop
' yourfile
```

---

---

### Explanations

- Skip empty, blank, and lines with NF > 1.
- Setup a do-while loop at the point where the pattern space holds a single-field line.
- We grab the next line and check whether it has NF > 1, at which point we print the whole pattern space and go back to reading the next line.
- Now we know that the next line also is single-field, so we go ahead and clip the newline joining these two portions in the pattern space.
- Does the pattern space have 3 spaces chunks yet? If yes then we print the whole of pattern space and start reading the next line.
- Otherwise, we branch back to the loop which will in turn read the next line but attach it to the existing pattern space.

### Result

```
1
4 5 6 7 19
20 22
24 26 27
29 30 31 32
34 40 50 56
58 100
234 235 270 500
1234 1235 1236 1237
2300 2303 2304 2307
2309
```

Answer (score 2):

**Usage:** `./join_rows.awk input.txt`

Check shebang `#!/usr/bin/awk -f`, because the `awk` location may differ on your system.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    count = 1;
}

{
    if (NF == 1) {
        if (count > 1 && count <= 4) printf " ";

        printf "%s", $1;
        count++;

        if (count > 4) {
            printf "\n";
            count = 1;
        }
    } else {
        if (count > 1) printf "\n";

        print;
        count = 1;
    }
}

END {
    if(count > 1) printf "\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
4 5 6 7 19
20 22 
24 26 27  
29 30 31 32
34 40 50 56
58 100
234 235 270 500
1234 1235 1236 1237 
2300 2303 2304 2307
2309
```

Comment: +1 for clarity. I would probably start `count` from zero, now I think `count == 1` means that there weren't any single-column rows.

Answer (score 1):

Extended ***gawk*** approach:

***rearrange_columns.awk*** script:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
function printRow(a, i, v)
{
    for (i in a) {
        printf "%s ", a[i]
    }
   print ""
   delete a
}
NF <= 2{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { 
        a[++c] = $i 
        if (length(a) == 4) {
            c = 0 
            printRow(a) 
        }
    }
}
NF > 2{
    if (length(a) > 0) {
        c = 0
        printRow(a)
    }
    print $0 
}
END{ print }
```

***Usage***:

```
awk -f rearrange_columns.awk yourfile
```

The output:

```
1 
4 5 6 7 19
20 22 
24 26 27 
29 30 31 32 
34 40 50 56 
58 100 
234 235 270 500
1234 1235 1236 1237
2300 2303 2304 2307 
2309
```

Comment: I added one row with two columns and your solution broke. For example, add one column to the 9-th row, new row will be `32 87`. I got this string in the output: `29 30 31 32 87 34 40 50 56 58 100`

Comment: @MiniMax, be more precise. You *added one row with two columns* in what position?

Comment: I was writing the row number - "to the 9-th row". Row which have one column with `32` value.

Comment: @MiniMax, ok, fixed. Thanks for checking out